# I need to call the `componentWillMount` of a page

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

i am using  `"react-native-router-flux": "^3.38.0"`. I need to call the `componentWillMount` of a page, but after the first time that it gets there the `componentWillMount` does not get called.

Edition:

please below find the code for navigation:

```
const RouterComponent = () => {
  return (
    <Router sceneStyle={{ paddingTop: 65 }} navigationBarStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#81b71a' }}>

      <Scene key='auth' initial>
        <Scene key='login' component={LoginForm} title='login here' />
      </Scene>

      <Scene key='main' >
        <Scene key='employeeCreate' component={EmployeeCreate} title='create employee' />
        <Scene
        initial
          key='employeeList'
          component={EmployeeList}
          title='Emplyees'
          rightTitle='add'
          onRight={() => Actions.employeeCreate()}
        />
        <Scene
          key='employeeEdit'
          component={EmployeeEdit}
          title='edit employee'
        />
      </Scene>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default RouterComponent;
```

Comment: Can you share the code you are using for navigation.

Comment: @DanPhilip edited

Answer (score 0):

It was a known issue in v3.38 which was fixed in a later version. Try updating the package to the latest version. [Issue](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/1612)

[4.0.0-beta.21](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-router-flux) is the latest

Comment: 4.0.0 got me through other issues and i was asked to move back to 38

Comment: What exactly do you need the `componentWillMount` for? Maybe there is a workaround.

Comment: When ever that page is shown i need to call an action creator.

Comment: yes but it didn't work as i need the action to be called only once when the page is up